# How to read RAW RestApi response C#

Tags: c#, rest, response, raw

How to read a raw response and display as is as a string.
I am getting the response as below. How to extract the below response as string
{
"ProductDescription":
{
"ProductId": "1000222",
"ProducName": "iphone13Case"
},
"ProductDetails":{
"ProductDetails":
{
"ProductId": "1000222",
"ProducCode": "Apple13",
"ProducName": "iphone13Case",
"ProductColor": "Red",
"ProductModel": "iPhonePro"
}
}
}

```
public Class ProductDescription
{
  public string ProductId;  
  Public string ProducName;
}

public Class ProductDetails
{
  public string ProductId;
  public string ProducCode;
  Public string ProducName;
  Public string ProductColor;
  Public string ProductModel;
}

Public Class ProductOrderDetails
{
  public ProductDetails prodDetails;
  public ProductDescription prodDescription
}

ProductOrderDetails response = RestApiMethod(param1, param2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. I am using Newtonsoft. `responseString` will now contain the response as a string with indentation.

```
var responseString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response, Formatting.Indented);
```